# Best way to filter over object's property by value

Tags: c#

```
class Sample
{
    public type1 Prop1 {get; set;}
    public type2 Prop1 {get; set;}
    public type3 Prop1 {get; set;}
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    public typen Propn {get; set;}
    
}
```

The problem is as follows:
Say I have a list of Sample objects. I have to provide funcionality to filter objects over a specific property by a specific value.
The method should be as follows:

```
List<Sample> filter(string propertyName, string value)
{
    ...
}
```

The intuitive approach I came up with is to switch case on propertyName, try to parse the input value to its real type
and then make the comparison. What disturbs me is that if the object has many properties, this solutions results with
logic duplication. My question is whether do you know of a better solution that doesn't use reflection.

Thanks.

Comment: _"that doesn't use reflection"_ Why not?

Comment: Because I know it is time consuming and I want to avoid it if possible.

Comment: [Did you test it?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: You have 3 solutions the good, the bad and the ugly. The good : reflection, clean, meant to do this. The bad use a single `Dictionary<string,object>` for all your properties instead, this is very bad and you loose tons of features. The ugly, type all your if statement.

Comment: That look like a `Func<TSource,int,bool> predicate`. wher you will pass `filter(x=> x.Prop1 == 42 )`. ANd if you have Property name as string `Expression<Func<TSource,int,bool>>`

Comment: Related :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726740/c-sharp-linq-where-clause-according-to-property-name

Comment: Reflection itself is not as time consuming as you think, as most common scenarios are heavily cached (getting properties would be one such scenario). Even where not, you can easily apply your own caching -- types don't change at runtime. Only in extreme cases do you need things like code generation (at runtime or compile time) to really eliminate it in the loops themselves.